# C - How do I split a line in a text file and store their values?

Tags: c, split, fgets

Let's say I have multiple lines in my text file:

```
print 1
set_flag 1 2 1
find_path 7 8
print 5
```

I want to be able to separate these values and apply it to my functions:

```
void print(int id) {...}
void set_flag(int a, int b, int c) {...}
void find_path(int from, int to) {...}
```

This is where I am stuck right now:

```
char str[256];
while(fgets(str, 256, filename) != NULL){
    //if a line contains "set_flag" then call set_flag(int a, int b, int c)
    if((strstr(str, "set_flag")) != NULL){
        //retrieve the str and all individual int values
        ...
    }
}
```

I have looked a bit online and found suggestions using strcmp, strstr, strtol and fscanf. Though the assignment recommends strtol to convert the readable values in the text file to 'correct' data types.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, as you seem to answer it yourself.  Use `strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the pointer of the matching substring, and then insert a NUL (`'\0'`) character at the end of that substring, which effectively splits the string into two separate strings.

But since all you really need is the location of rest of the string following the matching 'set_flag' in order to retrieve the integer values, you do not have to do that. Instead, you can simply find that location in the string:

```
// if a line contains "set_flag" then call set_flag(int a, int b, int c)
char *p = strstr(str, "set_flag");
if (p != NULL) {
    // str contains 'set_flag', which p now points to
    p += strlen("set_flag");
    // p now points to the rest of the string following 'set_flag'

    // retrieve the individual int values from the rest of the string
    ... // left as an exercise, sscanf(p, ...) ...
}
```

At this point, pointer `p` points to the character following 'set_flag' in the text line you have read from the input. You can then use `sscanf()` to extract the integer values from the string (which I leave as an exercise for you).

Comment: thanks, i took your suggestion to use sscanf and combined it with strncmp.